# The second-derivative of the log-likelihood function in logistic regression (page 120) model

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

In textbook The Elements of Statistical Learning, for logistic regression (page 120) model, the log-likelihood function can be written as
$$\ell(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i\beta^Tx_i-\log(1+e^{\beta^Tx_i}))$$
This is a $(p+1)$ nonlinear equations in $\beta$. To solve this problem, we use the Newton-Raphson algorithm, which requires the second-derivative
$$\frac{\partial^2 \ell(\beta)}{\partial \beta \partial \beta^T}=-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_ix_i^Tp(x_i;\beta)(1-p(x_i;\beta))$$
where $p(x_i;\beta)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta^Tx_i}}$.

My questions are
(1) why the second derivate is not defined by
$$\frac{\partial^2 \ell(\beta)}{\partial \beta ^2}?$$

(2) What is the result of
$$\frac{\partial \ell(\beta)}{\partial \beta^T}=\frac{e^{\beta^Tx_i}x_i}{(1+e^{\beta^Tx_i})^2}?$$
Is it same as $\frac{\partial \ell(\beta)}{\partial \beta}?$

Comment: we need a $nxn$ hessian. The notation used is to indicate that we have a square matrix (aka Hessian)

Comment: @sku That is not my question. My question is about the notation. Why we use $\frac{1}{\partial \beta \partial \beta^T}$ rather than $\frac{1}{\partial \beta^2}$?

Comment: This notation makes it explicit that result is a square matrix and not just a scalar.

Comment: Is this notation the same as $\nabla ^2$?

Comment: Also, why there is $x_i$ in numerator of $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta^T}$ but not $x_i^T$? However, there is $x_i^T$ in numerator of $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \beta}$?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused by the difference between univariate and multivariate differentiation.
Your first derivative is wrt to a vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and therefore is expected to be a vector itself (the collection of all partial derivatives). I.e. $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T}= \left[\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \beta_0},\ldots,\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \beta_p}\right]^T.$$
Now, the second derivative is formed by deriving every element  in $\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T}$ wrt to $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ *again*, so we have to form $p +1$ derivatives for each of the $p +1$ elements in $\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T}$, which results in a $(p +1) \times (p +1)$ matrix, the Hessian.

So to answer your first question, you have $\partial \beta^2$ in the denominator when you derive wrt to *one* coefficient (the univariate version) and you have $\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T\boldsymbol{\beta}$ in the denominator when you derive wrt to a vector (the multivariate version).

Your second question is related to the first question. The result of $\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}^T}$ is a vector and is therefore not the same as the result of $\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial\beta}$ which is a scalar.

Comment: why there is $x_i$ in numerator of ∂ℓ/∂β^T but not $x^T_i$? However, there is $x^T_i$ in the numerator of ∂ℓ/∂β?

Comment: Sorry, why $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}$ is not a vector?

Comment: It is not a vector because you do not derive with respect to a vector. The $\partial \beta$ in your denominator is not a vector.

Comment: Sorry, but you said $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta^T}$ is a vector?

Comment: Can you also write $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}$ precisely? Thanks.